# Merging two excel file into a third one with the common heading

Tags: linux, bash

I have two excel file with common headings "StudentID" and "StudentName" in both of the excel files. I want to merge these two excel files in to a third excel containing all the records from the two excel along with the common heading. How can i do the same through linux commands.

Comment: It is always recommended to post input and output in your post, kindly do so.

Comment: If you do perl, consider the [Spreadsheet::Read](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Read) and [Spreadsheet::Write](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Write) modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed it was csv files as it would be way more complicated with .xlsx files

```
cp first_file.csv third_file.csv
tail -n +2 second_file.csv >> third_file.csv
```

First line copies your first file into a new file called third_file.csv. Second line fills the new file with the content of the second file starting from the second line (escapes header).

Answer (score 1):

Due to your requirement to do this with "Linux commands" I assume that you have two CSV files rather than XLSX files.

If so, the Linux join command is a good fit for a problem like this.

Imagine your two files are:

```
# file1.csv
Student ID,Student Name,City
1,John Smith,London
2,Arthur Dent,Newcastle
3,Sophie Smith,London
```

and:

```
# file2.csv
Student ID,Student Name,Subjects
1,John Smith,Maths
2,Arthur Dent,Philosophy
3,Sophie Smith,English
```

We want to do an equality join on the Student ID field (or we could use Student Name, it doesn't matter since both are common to each).

We can do this using the following command:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 file1.csv file2.csv 
Student ID,Student Name,City,Subjects
1,John Smith,London,Maths
2,Arthur Dent,Newcastle,Philosophy
3,Sophie Smith,London,English
```

By way of explanation, this join command written as SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT `Student ID`, `Student Name`, `City`, `Subjects`
FROM `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`
WHERE `file1.Student ID` = `file2.Student ID`
```

The options to join mean:

The "SELECT" clause:

- `-o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3` means select the first file's first field, first file's second field, first file's third field,second file's third field.

The "FROM" clause:

- `file1.csv file2.csv`, i.e. the two filename arguments passed to join.

The "WHERE" clause:

- `-1 1` means join from the 1st field from the Left table
- `-2 1` means join to the 1st field from the Right table (-1 = Left; -2 = Right)

Also:

- `-t,` tells join to use the comma as the field separator

Answer (score 0):

@Corentin Limier Thanks for the answer.
Was able to achieve the same through similar way below.
Let's say two files a.xls,b.xls and want to merge the same into the third file c.xls

```
cat a.xls > c.xls && tail -n +2 b.xls >> c.xls
```